# Start timer immediately in Elm

Tags: elm

What I expected to the following code is to increment count asynchronously when I toggle timer on and off. But it always works synchronously (increments by 2).

How can I make it asynchronous?

EDIT: Maybe due to the shortage of my english capability, it seems the question is often misunderstood. I want the implementation which does exactly same behavior as my answer. And the point is, *That two timers should increment the count separately by toggling.*

```
import Html exposing (program, div, button, text)
import Html.Events exposing (onClick)
import Time exposing (every, second)

main = program
  { init = ({cnt = 0, on = True}, Cmd.none)
  , view = view
  , update = update
  , subscriptions = subscriptions
  }

subscriptions model = Sub.batch
  [ every second (always Increment)
  , if model.on then every second (always Increment) else Sub.none
  ]

view model = div []
  [ button [ onClick Toggle ] [ text "-" ]
  , div [] [ text (toString model) ]
  , button [ onClick Increment ] [ text "+" ]
  ]

type Msg = Increment | Toggle

update msg model =
  case msg of
    Increment ->
      ({model | cnt = model.cnt + 1}, Cmd.none)
    Toggle ->
      ({model | on = not model.on}, Cmd.none)
```

Comment: For sake of clarity: You expect the output displayed to be: 1, 2, 3, 4 irrespective of whether the model.on is True or false.

model.on should only affect the speed at which the display changes, based on when the toggle actually happened. 

but the problem is that when model.on is True, it shows 1, 3, 5. Instead of 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 at a different speed than before. 

Let me know if I understood your question properly.

Comment: @Jigar Yes. That's what I meant.

Answer (score 0):

Hack to this problem is the following, but it of course wouldn't be desirable. I want to use other solution as much as possible. Please provide reliable method for me.

```
import Html exposing (program, div, button, text)
import Html.Events exposing (onClick)
import Time exposing (every, second)

main = program
  { init = ({cnt = 0, on = True}, Cmd.none)
  , view = view
  , update = update
  , subscriptions = subscriptions
  }

subscriptions model = Sub.batch
  [ every (second + 0.0000000001) (always Increment)
  , if model.on then every second (always Increment) else Sub.none
  ]

view model = div []
  [ button [ onClick Toggle ] [ text "-" ]
  , div [] [ text (toString model) ]
  , button [ onClick Increment ] [ text "+" ]
  ]

type Msg = Increment | Toggle

update msg model =
  case msg of
    Increment ->
      ({model | cnt = model.cnt + 1}, Cmd.none)
    Toggle ->
      ({model | on = not model.on}, Cmd.none)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a version that counts up by 1 per second while `on`, and always allows manually incrementing by 1.

```
import Html exposing (program, div, button, text)
import Html.Events exposing (onClick)
import Time exposing (every, second)

main = program
  { init = ({cnt = 0, on = True}, Cmd.none)
  , view = view
  , update = update
  , subscriptions = subscriptions
  }

subscriptions model = Sub.batch
  [ every second (always Tick)
  ]

view model = div []
  [ button [ onClick Toggle ] [ text "Toggle" ]
  , div [] [ text (toString model) ]
  , button [ onClick Increment ] [ text "+" ]
  ]

type Msg = Tick | Toggle | Increment

update msg model =
  case msg of
    Increment ->
      ({model | cnt = model.cnt + 1}, Cmd.none)

    Tick ->
      case model.on of
        True ->
          ({model | cnt = model.cnt + 1}, Cmd.none)
        False ->
          (model, Cmd.none)

    Toggle ->
      ({model | on = not model.on}, Cmd.none)
```

Comment: I added additional clarification to my question. There was an answer like yours.